# Why does JDBC code work in Java but return null in Android?

Tags: java, android, database, jdbc, nullpointerexception

fellow stackers. I'm using android studios. As the title indicates; I've managed to get JDBC to work in java, but not on android. I made a class dedicated for everything database related. Both my Java code and my android code are in the same folder and have the EXACT same code.

A function in my database class returns an ArrayList of results, fetching this list works perfectly fine in java, but in android, it returns null, which results in a `NullPointerException`.

I've done some research on the matter and I am using the `INTERNET persmission` as well as calling the database class from an async class.

Any suggestions?

Edit: My database is hosted on a webserver.

Comment: you saying result set is null? if so , there should be other problem that lead into this. Postyour stacktrace if possible. Probably your query failed, or connection failed . Something else must have happened . It is possible that you have handled exception impropery , swallowing the main cause. So debug around where you are making connection and executing query.

Comment: I see now that I had the exception return null. Definitely a key to solving this issue. How would I view the stacktrace? I'm having some issues initializing a log to work with it.

Comment: Here we go. The exception I received was; "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver"

Comment: Probably the driver you are using is not compatible with android (dalvik jvm? ) or the library is not properly added. good luck

Comment: Make up your mind. Does it return null, as per your title, or throw `NullPointerException`, as per your text? 'Had the exception return null' is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, everyone, for your help - I've discovered the root of the issue. In the try/catch, I returned null instead of logging the error when caught. The issue lies in the driver: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver". I ought to be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

It works in Java because you're most likely connected to a database in your very own machine (I'm guessing you're trying to access localhost).

In Android, it doesn't work that way. Localhost in android would be your smartphone and you probably don't have any database in it.

My suggestion: create some sort of webservice that connects to your database and returns the results to your android application. It acts as a bridge between your DB and your app.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. My apologies, this is something I should've mentioned in my original post: My database is hosted on a server. I've had no issues with the server/database these past months and there shouldn't be any issues on that end.

Comment: This new information somewhat invalidates my answer. Are you using HttpURLConnection inside your AsyncTask to access your webserver? Or maybe check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

Comment: I've been using DriverManager.getConnection(), thus far.